# pandas .agg(['mean'])で正確な値を求めることができない。

Tags: python, pandas

**〇実行環境**
Windows 10
Python 3.X
pandas

こちらのリンクでの質問内容の続きになります。
[pandasでの特定の条件下でのデータ取得ができない。](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/93032/pandas%E3%81%A7%E3%81%AE%E7%89%B9%E5%AE%9A%E3%81%AE%E6%9D%A1%E4%BB%B6%E4%B8%8B%E3%81%A7%E3%81%AE%E3%83%87%E3%83%BC%E3%82%BF%E5%8F%96%E5%BE%97%E3%81%8C%E3%81%A7%E3%81%8D%E3%81%AA%E3%81%84)
**〇リンク先の質問**
上記のリンクではpandasを使用して各idがカラムのどの「分類」に属しているかの質問をし、groupbyを使用して、各idごとの分類と数値を取得することができました。

〇質問内容
上記の質問から次のようなdfxを取得することができました。

〇dfx(区切りが見やすいよう、csv形式にしています。）

```
id,数値,分類
aaa,3141,type2
bbb,5926,type1
ccc,5358,type3
ddd,9793,type1
eee,2384,type3
fff,6264,type2
ggg,3383,type2
hhh,2795,type1
iii, 288,type3
jjj,4197,type1
kkk,1693,type3
lll,9937,type2
mmm,5105,type2
nnn,8209,type1
```

このデータからカラム「分類」の三つの要素ごとに最大値、最小値、平均値を求めたいと思っております。
下記のソースで最大値と最小値は求めることができたのですが、平均値だけ以上に大きく明らかにおかしい数値が出てしまいました。

最小値、最大値は求められていたのでデータ値に誤りがあるとは思えないのですが、
何かおかしい点はありますでしょうか？

```
#平均値を求める
dfx_mean = dfx.groupby('分類').agg(['mean'])
```

〇出力された値
'''
mean
分類
type1  8886377.5
type2  2.76252E+86
type3  1.85807E+15
'''

Comment: 手元の環境は Pandas 1.5.2 ですが、実行結果は `type1 6184.00`, `type2 5566.00`, `type3 2430.75` になります。`dfx_mean = dfx.groupby('分類')['数値'].agg(list)` を実行して、それぞれの分類に含まれる数値を確認してみてはどうでしょうか。

Comment: リストに3桁又は4桁の数値が格納されていることが確認できました。ほかに原因となる要素はありますでしょうか？@metropolis

Comment: それでは `Numpy` の `mean()` を使うとどうなるでしょうか。`import numpy as np` として、`dfx_mean = dfx.groupby('分類')['数値'].agg([np.mean])` として、結果を確認してみて下さい。

Comment: excelを読み込んだのなら、そう明確に書きましょう。そして、正しく読み込めてることを確認しましょう。

Comment: ’数値’列の型が数値型ではなく、objectだったため正しくsortされませんでした。**dfx['数値'] = dfx['数値'].astype('int64')**で型を変更したら当初のコードで正しく動きました。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`agg(['mean'])` の結果だけが可怪しいのであれば, その処理を(何らかの要因で)書き換えてしまった可能性があります。
`dfx`の内容を(例えば) CSVなどの形式で保存し, 別環境で読み込み `agg(['mean'])` が正しい値で得られるならば, 原因は 「処理が置き換わった」<del>ことでしょう</del> 可能性があります。
(別環境でも失敗するのであれば手順を質問に追記してみてください)

---

##### 追記

原因は, 数値型でなかった ことのようですが
`agg` に与える関数名には以下のようなものもあります。参考に。

数値項目でなければエラーになるパターン

```py
>>> dfx.groupby('分類').agg({'数値': 'ohlc'})   # '数値'項目だけ対象にするので辞書形式で

        数値
        open    high    low     close
分類              
type1   5926    9793    2795    8209
type2   3141    9937    3141    5105
type3   5358    5358    288     1693
```

あとほかに `'dtypes'` も指定可能 (リスト指定ではなく 1項目で指定)

```py
df.groupby('分類').agg('dtypes')
```